# QWebView: is it possible to highlight terms and do keyboard navigation?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using QWebView from PyQT4. I'd like to

1. highlight terms of a webpage.
2. do a keyboard navigation inside a webpage (for example Ctrl-N move to next link)

is it possible?

Comment: I would split this question in two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. not trivial, but possible.  You could use the [toHtml](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebframe.html#toHtml) method of your `QWebView` instance, parse it e.g. with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (be sure to stick with 3.0.9!-), insert a `<span class="myhilite">...</span>` around whatever terms you like (as well as the CSS to define exactly what visual effects class `myhilite` is going to have), and put the modified HTML back with the `setHtml` -- phew;-).
2. I guess you could, by using the appropriate functionality that `QWebView` inherits from [QWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#public-functions) (I don't think `QWebView` adds any extra relevant functionality of its own), e.g. [grabKeyboard](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard) if you want to grab all keyboard events, or maybe [addAction](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#addAction) with an appropriate [shortcut](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qaction.html#shortcut-prop) -- but I'm not sure exactly what you want to happen when control-N is pressed, so this one is iffier.  Maybe you can clarify in terms of the many possible methods of `QWebView`, `QWidget`, etc...?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to [Qwebview findText()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwebview.html#findText) method.

```
 bool QWebView::findText ( const QString & subString,QWebPage::FindFlags  options = 0 )
```

> Finds the specified string, subString,
>   in the page, using the given options.
>
> If the HighlightAllOccurrences flag is
>   passed, the function will highlight
>   all occurrences that exist in the
>   page. All subsequent calls will extend
>   the highlight, rather than replace it,
>   with occurrences of the new string.

Comment: @pierocampanelli it's trivial to test